# Hashing password on hapi.js is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt, hapi.js

in my database, password are stored using hashing. But when i try to send plain password to compare with stored password on db it's not working. I'm using bcrypt npm to hash password. I'm using hapi.js server.

```
//user authentication
const validate = async (req, username, password, reply) => {

const user = await usermodel.findOne({username, password}).exec(); 

const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

if(match) {
    let isValid = username === user.username;
    return isValid;
}
   return { 
         isValid: isValid, 
    };
 };

const init = async () => {

try {
   await server.register(auth);
   server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', {validate});
   server.auth.default('simple');

  await server.start();
  console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
   } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
   }
 };

 init();
```

but unfortunately every time when i give password, i get this error :

> Debug: internal, implementation, error
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null
>
> Debug: internal, implementation, error
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null

Comment: The error suggests that `user` is `null`. If so, that problem is unrelated to hashes.

Comment: no im giving the right username always. when i'm not using hashing it's working but after using bcrypt.comparison it's not wokring

Comment: Like Jonas explains, your DB query will always return `null`. I'd hash the password first, then query for `username, passwordHash`. That should return a match if the login is valid.

Comment: why would i hash the password again? when it's already hashed in db @ChrisG

Comment: In the above code, is `password` the plaintext password, yes or no?

Comment: yes password is the plaintext but using `await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)` aren't i matching that plaintext to db password? but whenever i tried to do this i got that error `Cannot read property 'password' of null` @ChrisG

Comment: How is `usermodel.findOne({username, password})` supposed to find the user if `password` is plaintext and the db contains hashes...? `user` is **always** `null` because there's never a match. Which is why you get the error when trying to access `user.password`.

Comment: Like I already told you, hash the user-submitted plaintext password first, then run your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash the password first, then run your query:

```
const validate = async (req, username, password, reply) => {
  const pwHash = await bcrypt.hash(password);
  const user = await usermodel.findOne({ username, password: pwHash }).exec();
  return user !== null;
};
```

No further checks are necessary. The `findOne()` command will go through all users and return the first match for both the `username` and `password` field, or `null` if there is no match.
Which means if the line returns a `user`, then `username === user.username` and `pwHash === user.password` *implicitly*.

The final line will return `true` if a match was found in the database, or `false` if no match was found.

Comment: what i understood was the user submitted password is that which you are giving pwHash to hash. but in the findOne function aren't i supposed to give my column name 'password' from mongodb?

Comment: Right, I fixed my answer.

Comment: but before hashing to match username and password i was using `isValid = username === user.username && password === user.password` and then just return the `isValid`. but now what should i give here will this be same? because it's not logging in

Comment: I guess you need to `return user !== null;` I based my return value on the part of your code that returns `{ isValid: isValid };`

Comment: Note that what you did before doesn't make sense, because that username and password are a match is a given if the database query returns a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
 usermodel.findOne({username, password})
```

That won't match any user, as the `password` you are using for searching is the unencrypted one, while the ones in the database are encrypted. Instead only search for the username, and exit early if that wasn't found:

```
const user = await usermodel.findOne({ username }).exec(); 
if(!user) return { isValid: false };
```

Comment: then what should i give here?